# Laravel Eloquent ORM - Removing rows and all the inner relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables, `table1`, `table2`, and `table3`. `table1` is one-to-many to `table2` and `table2` is one-to-many to `table3`.

I want to invoke `Table1::find($id)::delete()` and have all the rows from `table2` and `table3` deleted as well.

I added the following to my tables:

**Table1**

```
public function delete()
{
    $this->table2()->delete();
    return parent::delete();
}
```

**Table2**

```
public function delete()
{
    $this->table3()->delete();
    return parent::delete();
}
```

However, my rows from `table3` are not deleted. `Table3`'s rows get deleted if I manually call the delete function from the model `table2`. The way I have written the code, shouldn't the `delete()` function from `table2` be called when `table1` calls it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call delete() on the collection, neither load far related collection on the query builder, to remove related models, so what you need is this:

```
// Table1 model
public function delete()
{
  $this->table2->each(function ($model2) {
    $model2->table3()->delete();
  });

  $this->table2()->delete();
  return parent::delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will delete sequentially all related ones:

```
// Table1
public function delete()
{
    $this->table2()->delete();
    $this->table2()->table3()->delete();
    return parent::delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this from laracasts and found it useful for me.
Let me paste the answer here:
So I have two models - User and Property User.php

```
public function properties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Property');
    }
```

Property.php

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Thus, if I want to delete a particular user, and of course, I don't want any his properties to be retained in the database:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $user->properties()->delete();

        $user->delete();

        return [
            'message' => 'Delete Complete!'
        ];
    }
```

I hope you or anyone else finds this useful! Regards :)

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-delete-model-with-all-relations