# Laravel Eloquent ORM - removing rows and all the child relationship, with event deleting

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-events

I have three models that relate to each other one to many:

### Country

```
class Country extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['name','sort'];
    public $timestamps=false;

    public function region(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Region');
    }
}
```

### Region

```
class Region extends Model
{

    protected $fillable=['country_id','name','sort'];
    public  $timestamps=false;

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Country');
    }

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');
    }
}
```

### City

```
class City extends Model
{
    protected $table='cities';
    protected $fillable=['region_id','name','sort'];
    public  $timestamps=false;

    public function region()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Region');
    }
}
```

When we remove the country automatically, remove all child item relationship, that is, removed and regions and city this country

I am doing so:

### Model Country

```
    public  static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($country) {
            //remove related rows region and city

            // need an alternative variation of this code
            $country->region()->city()->delete();//not working
            $country->region()->delete();

            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

### OR

### Model Region

```
public  static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        // this event do not working, when delete a parent(country)
        static::deleting(function($region) {
            dd($region);
            //remove related rows city
            $region->city()->delete();
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

**options with cascading deletes database, please do not offer**

## UPDATE

**I found the answer**

use closure for query builder, to remove related models

### Model Country

```
public  static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($country) {
            //remove related rows region and city
            $country->region->each(function($region) {
                $region->city()->delete();
            });
            $country->region()->delete();//
            return true;
        });
    }
```

[Laravel Eloquent ORM - Removing rows and all the inner relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232912/laravel-eloquent-orm-removing-rows-and-all-the-inner-relationships)

Comment: did you try `$this->region()->city()->delete();` ?

Comment: @K.Toress tried, BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::city()

Comment: Have you tried deleting the city before you delete the region in the `Model Country` one?

Comment: @Björn how make, after all in model Country:                                                                             `$country->region()->city()->delete();
 $country->region()->delete();`                                  BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::city()

Comment: You can set `->onDelete('cascade')` for the column in your migrations either.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick recap:

`$model->related_model` will return the related model.
`$model->related_model()` will return the relation object.

You can do either `$model->related_model->delete()` or `$model->related_model()->get()->delete()` to access the `delete()` method on the model.

Another way of handling the deletion of related (or sub) models is to use foreign key constraints when you write your migrations, check https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: on the collection can't call delete()

Comment: Ah - in that case just loop through all the models in a collection and delete them individually, or run use the [query builder delete](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#deletes) method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in the delete function of the parent object:

```
public function destroy_parent($id)
{
    $parent = PARENT::find($id);
    foreach ($parent->childs as $child){
            $child->delete();
    }
    $parent->delete();
    return redirect(...);
}
```